# why javascript function not get called in mvc 5 razor page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to asp.net and javascript. I dont understand why any of the following three javascript functions never get called when I click the button. Can anyone help?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    userId = item.Id;
    <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="btn-group" onclick="getElementById('@userId').innerHTML=Add(1,2)">Reset Password</button>
        </td>
        <td id="@userId">
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Add(a, b)
{
    return a+b;
}
function RequestResetPassword()
{
    var str = "@userId";
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Account/ResetPassword",
        data: "id=" + "@userId",
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg );
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        alert("alert");
        //$.post("/Account/ResetPassword",
        //    {
        //        id: userId,
        //    },
        //    function (data, status) {
        //        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        //    });
    });
});
```

Comment: is button in a form? If so need to prevent default form submit. Any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: does it mean any javascript function will be called automatically when page load, even if you did not click the button? if so, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
<button class="btn-group" onclick="RequestResetPassword('@item.Id')">Reset Password</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
function RequestResetPassword(id)
{
    alert("id = " + id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Account/SendResetPasswordEmail",
        //data: "id=" + id,
        data: { "id": id },
        //dataType: "json",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("msg = " + msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
    alert("ajax finished")
}
```